# Call method hierarchy in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, scope

I declare a class method:

```
+(int)widthScaled:(UIImage *)image maximumHeight:(int)max{
    int width = 0;
    width = (image.size.width - (((image.size.height - max)*100)/image.size.height)*image.size.width)/100;

    return width;

}
```

In the same class, I declare an instance method like these:

```
- (void)generarVistas{
    if(...){
       ...
    }else{
         for(...){
               ...
//I need to put the class method here but if I call the class method like this, don't recognize
               int variable = [[self class] widthScaled:image maximumHeight:max];
...
}
}
```

I try to put the class method in instance method but doesn't work. 
What context should I indicate to recognize the class method?

Comment: Where you have declare your class method - In NSObject, UIViewController, AppDelegate, UIView....?

Comment: Create static variable of your class assign it in `-viewDidLoad` or `-init` method and then call instance method using this variable

Comment: But it's all in the same class

Comment: I test your implementation its work on my side. Can you please elaborate what warnings/errors show when you call that class method?

Comment: Sorry, possibly it's problem of my code cause I test writing a new instance method with the same structure (if...else...for) and works correctly... Thanks and sorry for having wasted your time...

Comment: If your question has been solved then accept the answer that helped you or add an answer if something else helped you please don't put in your question solved. I have removed this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is that `[self class]` is a runtime call who's return result is not known until runtime. The compiler doesn't know what class it is. The code you're writing must always be invoked from a fixed class, so don't do that. If the class is FooClass, then use this form:

```
int variable = [FooClass widthScaled:image maximumHeight:max];
```

(replace `[self class]` with your class name, e.g. `FooClass`.)

Comment: Ok, I sove de problem rewritting the code because probably some bracked was wrong. I call [self class] because the method I need to call is inside the same class I call the method. now with this work's correctly: widthImage = [[self class] widthScaled:imageProduct maximumHeight:maxHeight];

Comment: No. Don't use "[self class]". Use the name of your class, as I said in my answer.